# "Vitriol" vs "caustic comments"

Tags: expressions

In choosing whether to use the expression

> He spewed his usual **vitriol**

or

> He spewed his usual **caustic comments**

does one carry more weight than the other?

Comment: Logically they should be opposites. Vitriol is acid (especially sulphuric) while caustic means an alkali

Comment: I've always thought that "vitriol" sounded like a hair tonic.

Answer (score 4):

> Spewing vitriol

is a rather extreme form of expression. It evokes a flood of searing invective and abuse heaped upon the individual to whom it is addressed. "Spewing vitriol" is concise.

In contrast, I'd say that

> ...spewed his usual caustic comments

is a bit more mild. It carries slightly less weight, which is what you asked about. Caustic comments imply burning, scathing remarks, and are no small matter! However, this is where I see the difference:

- **Spewing vitriol** is completely descriptive in its own right
- **Spewing caustic comments** requires caustic as an adjective for "comments". So it seems slightly less inflammatory, less weighty than vitriol which stands on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I would say vitriol carries a more severe connotation and I believe also by denotation.

Answer (score 0):

The weight or strength of a statement depends on how effeciently it conveys the message, how easily it is understood by people. If the desire effect was for the statement to be as harsh as possible, which is possibly the case at present, then being *blunt* would be the best choice.

Now, "vitriol" is a word that is not commonly known, nor commonly used. Say it at the local market, and I don't think anyone's going to comprehend. Thus, if you were to say "He spewed his usual vitriol", sure that's alright, but is anyone going understand that you actually mean that the person is being extremely corrosive in his speech?

Definitely more people understand what "caustic comments" mean. Thus, I would say that both mean the same, but "He spewed his usual caustic comments" would be more understandable, and hence, carry more weight.

Answer (score 0):

"spew vitriol" is a metaphor;  vitriol is a liquid acid, so "spewing" it makes sense:  to "spew" means to vomit or spit forth a large amount of liquid.

"Spewing comments" is a mixed metaphor, with the "spew" from the idiom "to spew vitriol" (or "bullshit", as we say down in Texas) applied to "comments", and with a "caustic" added in for good measure.   That weakens the effect of the phrase from the start.   But then, there is the "caustic" added into the expression, which wouldn't be a problem if you followed the metaphor through ("Spewed his caustic froth into the faces of all present", "spewed his caustic bilge upon his wife's cringing ears", etc), but here, you don't.   So the phrase "spewed caustic comments" is doubly weakened relative to the idiomatic metaphor, "spewed vitriol."

Finally, if one just wanted to "spew" comments, that in itself would imply something unpleasant enough for most situations.  To "spew comments" would be to "vomit forth language without thought";  similarly, one could "spew invective", "spew insults", and so on.   In that context, "to spew vitriol" is among the most extreme and ugly of things to spew, but as indicated above, depending on where one uses "caustic", equally disgusting and horrifying images ("caustic bilge", "caustic froth", etc) can easily emerge.

So my point is twofold:  first, "caustic" can easily imply insult or invective as painful as "vitriol", simply because "vitriol" is an intensely caustic liquid -- "caustic" is the defining quality of "vitriol".  But secondly -- and here, perhaps more importantly -- don't mix your metaphors unless you really know what you're doing, because by doing so one will seriously weaken the effect of one's words.

Generally, someone who makes a "caustic comment" will be merely acerbic and biting, but given the right context (both socially and rhetorically), someone who makes a caustic retort/comment/insult/etc could easily be vitriolic in their effect, particularly if it is a public humiliation of a good-natured, soft-hearted or weak-willed soul.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, having used the phrase in a letter to describe my own behavior , the words, vitriolic and spew, aptly and succinctly describe some "caustic comments."